# How to execute javascript code in Flutter web app

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I have to use a JS library in my Flutter web app.

The library's guide says that write code as below (IMP.init, IMP.request_pay)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.iamport.kr/v1/iamport.js"></script>
<script>
    IMP.init("imp67011510");
    IMP.request_pay({
        pg : 'kcp',
        pay_method : 'card',
        merchant_uid: "IMP"+makeMerchantUid, 
        name : 'carrot 10kg',
        amount : 50000,
        buyer_email : 'Iamport@chai.finance',
        buyer_name : 'Paul',
        buyer_tel : '010-1234-5678',
        buyer_addr : 'Somewhere in Korea',
        buyer_postcode : '123-456',
        display: {
            card_quota: [0]
        }
    }, function (rsp) { // callback
        if (rsp.success) {
            console.log(rsp);
        } else {
            console.log(rsp);
        }
    });
    
</script>
```

So I tried to execute both functions (IMP.init and IMP.request_pay) in my Flutter web app.

First, added the library to the path ***/web/index.html*** in my project

```html
<head>
...
  <script src="https://cdn.iamport.kr/v1/iamport.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

Second, created Dart functions calling the JS function.

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('IMP.init')
external void init(dynamic text);

@JS('IMP.request_pay')
external void requestPay(dynamic obj, dynamic callback); // is it correct?
```

Third, wanted to call above Dart functions but I'm not sure what should be put in as the callback parameter and can't even know I've created requestPay() correctly.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> obj = {
  pg : 'kcp',
  pay_method : 'card',
  merchant_uid: "IMP"+makeMerchantUid, 
  name : 'carrot 10kg',
  amount : 50000,
  buyer_email : 'Iamport@chai.finance',
  buyer_name : 'Paul',
  buyer_tel : '010-1234-5678',
  buyer_addr : 'Somewhere in Korea',
  buyer_postcode : '123-456',
  display: {
    card_quota: [0]
  }
};

init("imp67011510");
requestPay(obj, callback);
```

So I wonder how I can call those JS functions in my Flutter web app.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain corrections that you can introduce in your code.

1. Adding the script tag: Try adding the script tag at the starting of the body tag.

```
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.iamport.kr/v1/iamport.js"></script>
...
</body>
```

2. Writing the JS functions: Create a `.js` file on the same level as `index.html` file in the web directory. Copy paste the following.

```js
function IMPHelper() { }

// Here the function takes two parameters. These params 
// will be later passed from the dart side. 
IMPHelper.prototype.init = (val, reqPayParams) => {
    const params = JSON.parse(reqPayParams);
    IMP.init(val);
    IMP.request_pay(params,
        // I think this callback fn can be defined here itself. 
        function (rsp) {
            if (rsp.success) {
                console.log(rsp);
            } else {
                console.log(rsp);
            }
        });
}
```

3. Writing the JS interop in the dart side.

- Create a file `imp_interop.dart`.
- copy paste the following code.

```dart
@JS()
library imp_interlop; // make sure the name is same as the file name

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS() // Same name as the JS Class we wrote above
class IMPHelper {
  external IMPHelper();

  external void init(String val, String params);
}
```

4. Now call the dart function in your app as:

```
Map<String, dynamic> obj = {
  pg : 'kcp',
  pay_method : 'card',
  merchant_uid: "IMP"+makeMerchantUid, 
  name : 'carrot 10kg',
  amount : 50000,
  buyer_email : 'Iamport@chai.finance',
  buyer_name : 'Paul',
  buyer_tel : '010-1234-5678',
  buyer_addr : 'Somewhere in Korea',
  buyer_postcode : '123-456',
  display: {
    card_quota: [0]
  }
};

IMPHelper.init('sfkjhjs', jsonEncode(obj));
```

This will execute your js function.

Hope this helps.

Note: You can [refer this](https://medium.com/stackademic/utilizing-js-library-for-flutter-web-c683c590927f) article as well if you want to look into this a bit more